# Having generated a webapp with the generator, how do I test my click on the device?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, click-packages

I used the webapp generator at http://developer.ubuntu.com/webapp-generator/ to create a web container for cheesy 80s radio station Magic (as heard in most London taxis). I now have a shiny new click package, which I can upload to the store, which is great - however it feels a bit untested.

I would like to install it on my phone prior to sharing it with the world, just so that if I made a typo in the URL or something I can catch it before embarrassing myself more than admitting listening to Magic already does.

How do I test a click package on my device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method I use for testing clicks is:-

1. Make the device accessible over `adb` using System Settings → About this phone → Developer Mode → Switch on.
2. Attach the device via a USB cable
3. Use `adb` to push the click package to the device

   ```
   adb push /path/to/your.click /tmp
   ```
4. Use `adb` to install the click package

   ```
   adb shell pkcon install-local --allow-untrusted /tmp/your.click
   ```
5. Pull down in the app scope to see the icon for your application appear

Comment: as said by Georakos Geor in an answer to this that is likely to be removed: `"I did what you told at your post but the result is this : Installing files [=========================]
Finished [=========================]
Fatal error: could not resolve: /tmp/****.****_0.4_all.click"`

Comment: Sounds like the "adb push" step failed. Check the click file is on the device using "adb shell" then look in /tmp

Comment: I  have run the commands and they seem to run OK but my webapp does not appear in the app scope.  Do you have a suggestion as to why this is?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I can't transfer that webapp to my BQ4.5

`alex@xc1706:~/Downloads$ cp /home/alex/Downloads/warumlinuxbesserist.wlbi_0.1_all.click /tmp/your.click 
alex@xc1706:~/Downloads$ sudo adb shell pkcon install-local --allow-untrusted /tmp/your.click

Installing files              [=========================]         

Finished                      [=========================]

Fatal error: could not resolve: /tmp/your.click`