# How install apps into ubuntu phone (Meizu pro 5) without connection to internet (by USB)?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

How can i install apps into Ubuntu phone by USB? Is there any method to download phone apps into desktop (MAC or Ubuntu) and then install them into phone by USB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that you can't.  Apps for the phone are in click packages.  The only simple way to install them is from the Ubuntu Store on your phone using a WiFi or a mobile data connection.

You can install click packages, if you have them, using USB (see [Having generated a webapp with the generator, how do I test my click on the device?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/603068/having-generated-a-webapp-with-the-generator-how-do-i-test-my-click-on-the-devi/603069#)) but there is no publicly available place you can get them from.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/AdbNetworking

Comment: adb is the tool that you would use to put a click package on a phone from a PC.  The problem is getting the click packages on your PC.  There is no way to get the click packages of the apps in the Ubuntu Store onto your PC.